# Children's book about an evil wizard and a giant

Tags: identification-request

I remember reading a short book as a child about an evil wizard and a giant. I don't remember all the details, but I do remember that the story ends with the wizard attempting to turn either the giant or the local town to stone, and his spell his reflected back at him (I think by a mirror owned by the giant?), which turns the wizard to stone instead.

Does anyone know what this story might be? It had a really distinctive art style, if I remember correctly. I think the latest it could've possibly been published would be the late 90's, but I suspect it might be a bit older than that.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Haven't seen you around these parts before ;-)

Comment: Were you ever able to find the name of this book? I too remember this book from my childhood and have been looking for the name and stumbled across this post from you. I remember I got it from a book drive at school back in the late 70s, so it has to be at least that old. I thought the name was "George the Gentle Giant", but after looking that name up, it's not the right one, although it was another book that I did used to have. Hopefully someone has the name.

Comment: Charlotte & Charles" by Ann Tompert has some matching details, but not the exact ending, it seems.